# Slide Back when Clicked Outside Of It

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to have my side slider button to smoothly slide back to position if the user clicks outside of it.

If you wanna check it here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKaAe/1/) of it

as of now it doesnt go back to position when you click outside of it.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideleft .mybutton').click(function () {
        var $lefty = $(this).parent();
        $lefty.animate({
            left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() + 31 : 0
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var $lefty = $('#slideleft .mybutton').parent();
        var container = $("#slideleft");
        if (parseInt($lefty.css('left')) == 0) if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            animate();
        }
    });
```

Here is a working fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakarikos/nzxmA/)

Answer (score 1):

Using some `event.target` trickery gives you this:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target !== $('#slideleft .mybutton')[0]) {
        $('#slideleft .mybutton').hide(); //or slide however you want to.
    }
});
```

If you notice this actually compares the actual HTML and not the jQuery object.
This is because `.target` give you back the actual HTML of what was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this works:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    var $lefty = $('#slideleft .mybutton').parent();
    if(parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0){
    $lefty.animate({
        left: -$lefty.outerWidth() + 31
    });
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKaAe/3/)